# Number of solution to a system of polynomial equations

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, multilinear-algebra

I have a system of $m$ Polynomial  equations $$f_i(x_1,\cdots,x_n)=\sum_{\begin{subarray}{l} S\subseteq[n]\\|S|\leq r\end{subarray}}c_{i,s}\prod_{j\in S}x_j=a_i,\;1\leq i\leq m,$$ where $c_{i,s}$ are coefficients that depends on the chosen subset $S$ and the number of equation $i$, and the degree of each equation is at most $r$.
What can I say at the maximal number of solutions to the system as a function of $m,n$ and $r$?

Comment: This is going to depend heavily on the coefficients $c_{i,s}$. In some cases the ideal generated by the $f_i$'s will be zero-dimensional, in others it will not.

Comment: Also, do you mean that the $c_{i,s}$ are chosen in such a way so that $f_i$ is multilinear? Because in general $f_i$ is not necessarily multilinear.

Comment: Maybe my understanding of multilinear functions is wrong. Basically in my case the coefficients are either zero or one. Each equation is a sum of products of $r$ variables out of the $n$. For example, $f_1$ can be $f_1=x_1x_6x_7+x_2x_6x_8+x_1x_6x_8+x_3x_4x_5$. In this example $r=3,n=8$.

Comment: I also know that the same product can’t appear in two different $f$’s, for example in the $f_1$ I gave in the previous comment the product $x_1x_6x_7$ appears, so it won’t appear in any other $f_i$, $2\leq i\leq m$.

Comment: Multilinear means linear in every variable. For $n=2$ and $r=1$ we might have $f(x,y)=x+y$ which isn't linear in any of its variables because $f(\lambda x,y)-\lambda f(x,y)=y-\lambda y$ and similarly for the other variable. Your function $f_1$ isn't linear in any of its variables.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I’ve edited the question to refer to polynomial equations.